# Problema com atualização de dado do banco (Android)

Tags: android

Não consigo atualizar o dado que está no banco de dados.

Na class do banco de dados estão as duas funções atualizar e buscarConfigurações.

```
public void atualizar(MessageEB dados){
    ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("data", dados.getData());

    bd.update("dados", valores, "_id = ?", new String[]{"" + dados.getId()});
    Log.i("a", dados.getData());

    bd.close();
}


public MessageEB buscarConfiguracoes() {
    MessageEB messageEB = new MessageEB();
    String sqlSelectTodosLivros = "SELECT * FROM dados";

    Cursor c = bd.rawQuery(sqlSelectTodosLivros, null);

    if(c.moveToNext()) {
        messageEB.setId(c.getLong(0));
        messageEB.setData(c.getString(1));
        Log.i("LOG", "funcao buscar");
    }

    Log.i("LOG", "fora do if "+(c.getString(1)));

    bd.close();
    return messageEB;
}
```

No fragment onde tem o EditText está esse código dentro de um:

```
public void onClick(View v) {


        MessageEB dados = new MessageEB();
        dados.setData(editar.getText().toString());
        BD bd = new BD(getActivity());
        bd.atualizar(dados);

    }
```

No fragment que vai exibir o dado:

```
txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.campoData2);
    BD db = new BD(getActivity());
    String s = db.buscarConfiguracoes().getData();
    txt.setText(s);
```

Qaundo o dado passa pela função atualizar o dado é alterado, vi isso com um Log, mas quando passa pelo buscarConfiguraçoes () o dado recebido é o mesmo de antes da alteração.

Comment: Como pode ter alterado se ao ler volta o valor anterior? O *log* gerado por `Log.i("a", dados.getData());` apenas lhe diz qual é o valor de `dados.getData` e não se o registo foi alterado com sucesso.

Comment: Para saber se um Update atualizou algum registo verifique o valor que ele retorna: `int linhasAtualizadas = bd.update("dados", valores, "_id = ?", new String[]{"" + dados.getId()});`. Faça o *log* desse valor. Se for zero o *Update* falhou.

Comment: Use `Integer.toString(intValor);`

Comment: Certo. Vou fazer isso agora.

Comment: De certeza que é zero. Veja a minha resposta.

Comment: Verdade. Mas quando eu inseri esse código ficou como erro o setId

Comment: Leu o cometário que está nessa linha. Ela está incompleta porque eu não sei onde você guardou o valor do *Id* do registo que quer alterar.

Comment: Muito obrigado! Resolveu meu problema. Valeu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está a criar uma nova instância de `MessageEB`, atribui-lhe o valor do *editText* e depois chama o método para atualizar os dados.

No entanto esse método necessita do valor do *Id*, valor esse que não é *"setado"* em `dados`.
Terá de alterar o código de forma a atribuir-lhe o *Id* do registo que quer alterar.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    MessageEB dados = new MessageEB();
    dados.setData(editar.getText().toString());

    dados.setId = //Não sei onde você o guardou

    BD bd = new BD(getActivity());
    bd.atualizar(dados);
}
```

Comment: Valeu! Deu certo.